# Print narrow strings using swprintf in C++Builder

Tags: c++, windows, printf, c++builder, widestring

The following lines both "work as intended":

```
wchar_t u[50], v[50];

swprintf(u, 50, L"%s", L"hello");
swprintf(v, 50, L"%ls", L"goodbye");

MessageBoxW(NULL, u, v, MB_OK);   // output: MessageBox showing "hello" and "goodbye"
```

Is there any way to print a narrow string, and where is the documentation for this? E.g.

```
swprintf(u, 50, L"%?", "hello");
```

---

The C++ Standard specifies (by reference to the C standard) that in the `wprintf` family of functions, `%s` specifies a string of `char` (in multibyte encoding, e.g. UTF-8), and `%ls` specifies a string of `wchar_t`.

So the RTL (run-time library implementation supplied with C++Builder) is apparently not standards-compliant here.

Background: I'm actually trying to use `UnicodeString::sprintf`, however that delegates the heavy lifting to `vswprintf`.

Comment: The runtime library supplied with C++Builder, containing the implementation of `vswprintf` etc.

Comment: Might be worth adding that detail into your question!

Comment: So have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit rewritten question for clarity. Not sure what you mean by "tried it".

Comment: Um, it means, what happened when you ran the program, and how did it compare to what you instead wanted to happen?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ran what program? I'm asking what should go in the place of "%?" in my code . I guessed "%Ws" but that caused an output of literally "%Ws".

Comment: I know you know the answer was _deleted_ as you are commenting here. So not sure why you're referencing it.

Comment: Just checking we're on the same page :) In any case, `%s` accepting `L"hello"` surely is not acceptable input for a standard-compliant implementation of `swprintf`.   I do have a recollection that MS invented their own stuff in this area (which C++Builder may have followed) but I couldn't find any more detail on that by googling.

Comment: It's not Borland-specific; MSVC does the same. I wouldn't be surprised if Borland used the windows runtime libraries (as does MSVC), so possibly it's a bug in them. It looks like a bug to me, in any case.

Comment: I would concur, if Matt had told us what happens when he runs the code. As it stands it's really hard to tell from this question _what the behaviour is_ that he's asking about and, by extension, whether it can be attributed to a bug.

Comment: Only slightly related, MS also has inversion printing [using `%S`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx). `swprintf` expects a narrow string, and vice-versa with `sprintf` expecting a wide-string. just fyi (and adding unnecessary fuel).

Comment: Found my own answer in the source code(sorry for wasting your guys' time, I should have looked there in the first place). I suppose the lesson from all this is to not touch sprintf!  Originally I was hoping to use it to avoid wasted allocations in a solution of `+`ing many wide string objects but correctness beats micro-optimization!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but more of a compilation of elements.

### Reference :

The site http://www.cplusplus.com/ is clear: for the `wprintf` family : *... all format specifiers have the same meaning as in printf; therefore, %lc shall be used to write a wide character (and not %c), as well as %ls shall be used for wide strings (and not %s)*

### Implementations :

gcc and clang both conform to above specification

MSVC and according to OP Borland C++ do not conform and accept `%s` for a wide string.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find this in the `vprinter.c` file in the RTL source code (C++Builder comes with its own RTL, it doesn't reference MS):

```
            /* The 's' conversion takes a string (char *) as
             * argument and copies the string to the output
             * buffer.
             *
             * Note: We must handle both narrow and wide versions
             * depending on the flags specified and the version called:
             *
             * Format           printf          wprintf
             * ----------------------------------------
             * %s               narrow          wide
             * %S               wide            narrow
             * %hs              narrow          narrow
             * %hS              narrow          narrow
             * %ls              wide            wide
             * %lS              wide            wide
             *
             */
```

so the code:

```
swprintf(v, 50, L"%hs", "hello");
```

generates the correct output.

However, this doesn't do any UTF-8 conversion; narrow characters are "widened" by attaching a null byte. (Confirmed by inspecting the resut of the source).

Comment: Note that the `UnicodeString::XXXprintf()` methods are broken on Android (and maybe other POSIX systems) for `%s` parameters. This is due to `vsnwprintf()` not being available, so `vsnprintf()` is used instead, and it requires UTF-8 for `%s`. This issue is discussed in QC #105241 and #124607.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In Standard C and C++, the `swprintf` family all take the length parameter, so `vswprintf` is the ultimate function (there is no `snwprintf` or `vsnwprintf`).  The standard specifies UTF-8 (or other MB encoding) for `%s` so it seems that the Android version is correct and the Windows version is broken.  It's understandable that Borland chose to follow MS instead of the standard, and Embarcadero doesn't want to revert to the standard, but now we have an icky mess.

Comment: Looking up QC 124607 gives me the not found / unauthorized message. (105241 worked)

Comment: QC #124607 exists (I filed it), but was reported during a beta test so it was not a public ticket (at this point it probably should be, but I cannot promote it to public anymore). I will say that it is still an open ticket, though.